# Reading a file - fileName is not defined [error]

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I am completely new to JavaScript, and I am having a trouble with using fs.readFile() function.

I am required to read a file, and determine whether I have to call successFn (when err boolean is false) or errorFn (if err boolean is true).

When I err is false, however, I am trying to call an "extractor" function as a parameter -- extractor separates the data read into each word.

I am required to call fs.readFile, so I am required to use parameters and one of the parameters is fileName.

The grader is going to test my code using his own files, so I am not supposed to define fileName, yet I am being asked to define it (I understand why I am being asked to do it, but I feel that there should be a way to get around this issue.)

Also, JavaScript syntax is very not intuitive, so I might be making some mistakes with the syntax, but here is my code, and please let me know how I can fix my issue:

```
function readAndExtractWith(extractor) {
    fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            errorFn(err);
        }
        else {
            data = extractor();
            successFn(data);
        }
        return extractor;
    });
}
```

Comment: `fileName` is not defined because you never define it. Since you are using that in a function you need to pass the variable as an argument or specify it inside the function.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I understand why I am being asked to define fileName - it is because it was never defined inside the function or passed as an argument. However, there is no way for me to know what that fileName variable would be because it will be arbitrarily defined by the grader. I would like to know if there is any way that I can fix this issue while using fs.readFile and without hardcoding the fileName.

Comment: Either way you need to pass the file to `fs.readFile()` so it can process it. Where does `fileName` come from? Please include that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

`fileName` is not defined because you never define it. Since you are using that in a function you need to either pass the variable as an argument, specify it inside the function, or define it globally.

```
var fileName = "stackoverflow.jpg";

// when executing the function pass the fileName parameter
readAndExtractWith(extractor, fileName);

function readAndExtractWith(extractor, fileName) {
    fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            errorFn(err);
        }
        else {
            data = extractor();
            successFn(data);
        }
        return extractor;
    });
}
```